# Error while processing the php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, image-processing, runtime-error, gd

I'm working on a project and I want to display user profile dp on and image background when I'm testing my code on WAMP server its working fine and display things as i required with some error but when i try to test it with my server online then its does not show the image and also with and error of **failed to open stream: Connection refused in online**

```
<?php 


    $text = 'Name';
    $t2 = '1594878934116599';

    $image_url="dump/".rawurldecode(trim($t2)).".jpg";
    $text = 'Name';

        $randomNumber = rand(1, 3);
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/' . $randomNumber . '.jpg');
copyImage($im, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$t2."/picture?width=200&height=200",  60, 80);
function copyImage($im, $dp1_name, $x1, $y1,$name,$g,$h){
                $dp1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dp1_name);
                list($ow, $oh) = getimagesize($dp1_name);
                imagecopyresized($im, $dp1, $x1, $y1, 0, 0, 180, 180, $ow, $oh);
                            }


        $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        $font_path = 'LiberationSans-Bold.ttf';
        imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 8,39, $black, $font_path, $text);

        imagejpeg($im,$image_url);
        imagedestroy($im);


    ?>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code to see at which point exactly the two situations differ? Is the target folder on online server writable?

Comment: yes folder is writable

Comment: Ok, that's the simplest one, what is the difference in output of for instance `$im` or `$dp1` to start with?

Comment: Background image is stored in $im

Comment: I'm totally confused can you help me out when I'm running it in my localhost WAMP its stores correct output in the dump folder but does not show on the result page

Comment: So the right file is stored, but it doesn't show in the browser? Is the path to the file correct? What happens when you open the file (just doubleckick the file) from your dump folder? It's an image right? Still only able to make educated guesses here!

Comment: I have edited the question please check it

Comment: And the code of the result page (part where you show the image)?

Comment: This is only the code of result page error is only in php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81672/discussion-between-learner-and-tvgemert).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that following code is working just fine on my own local MAMP. I've removed some of the unused arguments from the `copyImage()` function, which caused warning messages. And re-ordered the code a bit. Added my own font and image but you could replace that again for your own. Try it out on your server. And if it gives errors than please post the error here.

```
<?php 

    function copyImage($im, $dp1_name, $x1, $y1){
        $dp1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dp1_name);
        list($ow, $oh) = getimagesize($dp1_name);
        imagecopyresized($im, $dp1, $x1, $y1, 0, 0, 180, 180, $ow, $oh);
    }

    $text = 'Name';
    $t2 = '1594878934116599';

    $image_url="dump/".rawurldecode(trim($t2)).".jpg";
    $text = 'Here the name';

    $randomNumber = rand(1, 3);
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('penguin02.jpg');

    copyImage($im, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$t2."/picture?width=200&height=200",  60, 80);

    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    $font_path = 'impact.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 8,39, $black, $font_path, $text);

    imagejpeg($im,$image_url);
    imagedestroy($im);

    echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'">';
```

Comment: It's also working fine on my WAMP server but on my online server following error are their **Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(https://graph.facebook.com/1594878934116599/picture?width=200&height=200): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/u447175929/public_html/newfile/main.php on line 4** second error **Warning: getimagesize(https://graph.facebook.com/1594878934116599/picture?width=200&height=200): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/u447175929/public_html/newfile/main.php on line 5**

Comment: and the last error **Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u447175929/public_html/newfile/main.php on line 6**

Comment: What is the `allow_url_fopen` setting for your server? And the `https://`is missing in your warning, strange. the last error is obvious because of the previous ones.

Comment: the graph.facebook http is hidden because its a ling which is too long

Comment: I'm using a free hosting server website for testing my projects they do not provide a setting `url` like `hostagator` and other server sites do I want to open he `FTP` from the main `hostinger` website only

Comment: Ok, then i guess you're out of luck. Find another host.

Comment: Sir, can you tell me why this errors are occuring this is because of the server only